# Find the path to my WSDL

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcftestclient

I have a silverlight 4 app.  When I made that it created 2 projects. My actual silverlight app and one called MySolutionName.web (not sure what that does except host my silverlight page).

Based on feed back from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261998/exception-in-brand-new-silverlight-project) I added my WCF stuff to the MySolution.web project.  But when I call the service from my silverlight app the value for my return object is empty (just has a property called PropertyChanged that is null).

I want to try calling the WCF service using WCF Test Client, but I don't know the URL for it.  How can I figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look on the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file within the Silverlight app project.

This file is created when you add service reference.
The endpoint element has an attribute address. I believe that's what you are looking for.
Because you are hosting your WCF in a different project than the one that host the Silverlight app 
you should make sure you have the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the solution/project that hosts the wcf services.
Below is an example of the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="http://*"/>
        <domain uri="https://*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

This file is used for crossdomain calls. By default Silverlight can only talk to the domain that originated the xap file.